# Active Directory / LDPA is not being authenticated with long Username

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to authenticate Active Directory User as follow:

Method 1:

```
bool IsValidUser = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName).ValidateCredentials(Username, Password);
```

Method 2:

```
DirectoryEntry DE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DomainName, Username, Password);
```

I have tried following credentials:

DomainName = `mydomain.local`

Username = `adminldapfooicxrecord`

Password = `adminldapfooicxrec0rd*`

With above Username `Method 1` is returning `false` while `Method 2` on `DE.Children` is throwing an error of `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

If Username would be `adminldapfooicxrecord@mydomain.local` it would work perfectly.

Why is this so ? Any clue ?

Comment: Windows will not allow the username and password as a string.  You must use the credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User accounts in Active Directory have two usernames, and you can authenticate using either one:

- [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) - This is what is commonly called the "username". It's also described as the "User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)" in AD Users and Computers
- [`userPrincipalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname) - This is a newer username field that was made to look like an email address. It is often made up of the `sAMAccountName` and `@` the domain name, and can even match the user's email address, but there is no technical requirement that this be true.

If you are using the `userPrincipalName` to login, then you must use the entire value, which includes `@mydomain.local`.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel Luci